# Proving that $GL_n(F)$ is non-abelian for $n \geq 2$ and for any field $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to show that $GL_n(F)$ is non-abelian for any field $F$ and $n \geq 2$. I'm doing so by constructing two $2 \times 2$ matrices that do not commute and "extending" them to $n \times n$ matrices with zeros in every other entry. We define $\displaystyle A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$ and $\displaystyle B = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{array}\right]$. A quick calculation reveals that $AB \neq BA$, so the products of the extended $n \times n$ matrices are also not equivalent.

My question is: does this suffice in proving the statement for any field $F$? The only field that I can think of where this might fail is in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, but that turns out to not be the case.

Comment: This does suffice. Provided that you do the extending in such a way that the resulting matrices are invertible (otherwise they are not elements of $GL_n(F)$). Using all zeros fails there, but another simple method suggests itself...

Comment: I see what you mean about how using zeros makes them potentially singular; however, I don't see the "simple method" you're referring to. Could you elaborate?

Comment: You can obtain $A$ and $B$ by applying a single elementary row transformation to the 2x2 identity matrix. What happens if you apply the exact same elementary row transformations to the nxn identity matrix?

Comment: Ok I see where you're going with this...but how do I show that the matrices don't commute? It's much easier to show for general $n$ when there are a bunch of zeros...

Comment: In addition to 2x2 blocks containing $A$ (resp. $B$) there will be an $(n-2)\times(n-2)$ identity block and two zero blocks along the wings. The block sizes are compatible for blockwise matrix multiplication, which makes the task much easier.

Answer (score 4):

As explained in the comments, the problem is one of extending the two matrices in such a way that 1) the same non-commutativity can be easily verified and 2) the matrices are non-singular.

A standard recipe is to extend by *ones along the diagonal and zeros elsewhere*.

Why is this "standard"? The way I think about it is in terms of linear transformations. Remeber that matrix multiplication is defined to faithfully represent composition of linear transformations (matrices are with respect to a given basis).

If $n>2$ we can write the vector space $V=F^n$ as a direct sum $V=F^2\oplus F^{n-2}$. The two matrices, $A$ and $B$, can be thought of as two linear transformations, $T_A$ and $T_B$, from $F^2$ to itself. Now we can define two linear transformations from $V$ to itself as follows. Using the above direct sum decomposition we can write any vector
$v\in V$ as $v=(x,y)$ with $x\in F^2$ and $y\in F^{n-1}$. Define $E_A:V\to V$ by declaring $E_A(v)=(T_A(x),y)$ and similarly define $E_B:V\to V$ by $E_B(v)=(T_B(x),y)$.
Because $T_A,T_B$ and the identity mapping of $F^{n-2}$ are all invertible, these linear transformations are both non-singular. They do not commute, because they do not commute on vectors of the form $v=(x,0)$ by your calculation. Thus we are done.

We also see that the matrices of $E_A$ (resp. $E_B$) with respect to the usual basis have the block structure
$$
E_A=\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
A&0\\
\hline
0&I_{n-2}
\end{array}\right)\qquad \text{and}\qquad
E_B=\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
B&0\\
\hline
0&I_{n-2}
\end{array}\right)
$$
respectively.

Answer (score 1):

$GL_n(F)\cong Aut(F^n)\,\, n\geq 3.$ where $F$ is an arbitrary field (not necessarily of characteristic zero). Let $f(x_1,x_2\cdots,x_n)=(x_2,x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ and $g(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)=(x_3,x_2,x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ Clearly $f,g\in Aut(F^n)$. Notice that  $f\circ g(1,0,0,\cdots,0)=f(0,0,1,0\cdots,0)=(0,0,1,0,\cdots,0)$ but $g\circ f(1,0,0,\cdots,0)=g(0,1,0,\cdots,0)=(0,1,0,\cdots,0).$ so $f\circ g\not=g\circ f.$

Comment: case $n=2$ you already proved it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen In characteristic zero, we can save this with a continuity argument.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to extend this result to characteristic $p$ without using the model completeness of algebraically closed fields...

Comment: @you-sir-33433, you can use Zariski topology! I guess that's what you were implying :-). Anyway, BigM corrected the example, so my objection is now moot. Thus I removed the comment.

Comment: For $n\ge 3$ we have $S_n \subset GL_n(F)$ and that group is non-abelian.

Answer (score 1):

You are only guaranteed the existence of element $0$ and $1$ in a field.

One possible approach is to define the following matrices:

$A = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         a_{ij} = 1 & \mbox{if $i = j$}\\
         a_{ij} = 1 & \mbox{if $i = 1$ and $j=n$}\\
        a_{ij} = 0 & \mbox{otherwise}.\end{array} \right.$

$B = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         a_{ij} = 1 & \mbox{if $i = -j$}\\
        a_{ij} = 0 & \mbox{otherwise}.\end{array} \right.$

Computing the product of both matrices:

$AB = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         a_{ij} = 1 & \mbox{if $i = 1$ and $j = 1$}\\
         a_{ij} = 1 & \mbox{if $i = - j$}\\
        a_{ij} = 0 & \mbox{otherwise}.\end{array} \right.$

$BA = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         a_{ij} = 1 & \mbox{if $i = n$ and $j = n$}\\
         a_{ij} = 1 & \mbox{if $i = - j$}\\
        a_{ij} = 0 & \mbox{otherwise}.\end{array} \right.$

So $AB \neq BA$

Edited: The original matrices were not invertible

Comment: While that does show that matrix multiplication need not be commutative in general, I don't believe either of those matrices are invertible.

Comment: I didn't take that into account. I have edited the answer so that the matrices are invertible and don't commute.